3x Lock remote starts in 1x Lock only
2008 Honda accord ex
Recently mechanic changed battery terminal and grounds due to starting issues. My car has the factory OEM remote start installed by Honda way back, it’s a 3x lock sequence and it works. But after the changin terminal and grounds due, the car starts in only 1 lock rather than 3. And it supposed to stay on for 10 minutes but now it stays on for 30-45 seconds.

Will be going back to mechanic to show this, but I due to time issues, anything I can do to troubleshot or fix? I have tried programming the key fob again but no luck

Have you looked at the settings on the vehicle setup screens? Something might have reset during the maintenance. I don't know about your Accord, but on many vehicles the operator is capable of changing how different things behave. Might be worth checking through your owners manual or even just perusing the  settings themselves.
